# Bukkit nullpointerexception

Tags: nullpointerexception, bukkit

Does anyone knows how to fix this nullpointerexception?
https://haste.nycode.de/gipicaxune.avrasm

Silvan

Comment: Can you add your code ? The world seems not found

Answer (score 0):

The world you are trying to load with your code (`Bukkit.getWorld("myWorld");`) in class `InventoryListener` in line `55`.

Before you handle optional information you should check if it exist.

Example:

```java
if(Bukkit.getWorld("myWorld") == null) {
    return;
}

Bukkit.getWorld("myWorld").//do something
```